# External vs Internal Symbols in Common Lisp Package

Tags: package, lisp, common-lisp, sbcl

What is the difference between them in the context of a Common Lisp package? I am reading through SLIME documentation and some commands mention that extensively.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The author of a Common Lisp package can export a symbol for the user of the package. Then the symbol is an external symbol and you can access it with `package-name:external-symbol-name`.

Internal symbols are not meant for the user but can be accessed with `package-name::symbol-name`

More explanations are in [Peter Seibel's book](http://www.gigamonkeys.com/book/programming-in-the-large-packages-and-symbols.html) and [Common Lisp the Language](http://www.cs.cmu.edu/Groups/AI/html/cltl/clm/node111.html)

Comment: What is the syntax for declaring those inside a package?

Comment: There is an example in the chapter about packages in Peter Seibel's book (I added the link in my answer) P.s.: I also am a mad physicist. What are you mad about?

Comment: A lot of things ... The state of academia, the group think, the quantum mechanics, etc. You?

Comment: Mostly myself, but don't get me started about quantum physics. Those darn particles can never make up their minds!

Comment: I think it is the physicists who have not made up their minds ;)

Answer (score 8):

What is the syntax ? The symbols you `export` are external.

```
(in-package :cl-user)
(defpackage str
  (:use :cl)
  (:export
   :trim-left
   ))

(in-package :str)

;; exported: can be accessed with `str:trim-left`.
(defun trim-left (s)
  "Remove whitespaces at the beginning of s. "
  (string-left-trim *whitespaces* s))

;; forgot to export: can still access it with `str::trim-right`.
(defun trim-right (s)
  "Remove whitespaces at the end of s."
  (string-right-trim *whitespaces* s))
```