# Lisp exports internal symbols

Tags: package, common-lisp, asdf

I am learning to define a system and have made a small testing package named **test**. It's structure looks like the following:

```
test/
  test.asd
  hi.lip
  hito.lisp
  package.lisp
```

Now in package.lisp file i define my package:

```
(in-package :cl-user)

(defpackage :test
  (:use #:cl)
  (:import-from #:uiop
        #:strcat)
  (:export #:sayhito))
```

and in test.asd the system:

```
(defsystem test
  :name "Testing"
  :components ((:file "package")
           (:file "hi")
           (:file "hito")))
```

In hi.lisp i have a helper function `sayhi` which isn't meant to be external:

```
(in-package :test)

(defun sayhi () "Hi")
```

and in hito.lisp the external function of the system `hito`:

```
(in-package :test)

(defun sayhito (name)
  (strcat (sayhi) " " name "!"))
```

I also have a directory /home/amir/lisp-link-farm/ where i put symbolic links of all my ASDFs into. Then in my lisp initialization file (.sbclrc) i have pushed this path into `asdf:*central-registry*`:

```
;;; The following lines added by ql:add-to-init-file:
#-quicklisp
(let ((quicklisp-init (merge-pathnames "quicklisp/setup.lisp"
                                   (user-homedir-pathname))))
  (when (probe-file quicklisp-init)
    (load quicklisp-init)))


;; where i am restoring symlinks to systems
(require 'asdf)
(push #p"/home/amir/lisp-link-farm/" asdf:*central-registry*)
```

Now when i load the test system by `(ql:quickload :test)` and change the package to `(in-package :test)` the internal helper function `hi` is also accessible as an external symbol! I can just do:

```
(sayhi)   ;; -> "Hi"
```

But if i don't change the package (so without `(in-package :test)` in the REPL) trying to call `(test:sayhi)` lisp complains that `sayhi` is not an external symbol in package test, while `(test:sayhito "Lisp")` works as it should.
Why is this happening and what am i doing wrong? Any help is appreciated.

Comment: related: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47782593/external-vs-internal-symbols-in-common-lisp-package/47790600#47790600

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No, it is not accessible as an external symbol.  As you wrote yourself, you changed the package to the package in question, and that means that it is your *current package*, and all symbol resolution works *internally*.  It is just the same as when you write code in a specific package: you can refer to all symbols of the package without prepending the package.

Note that even if you changed your current package to `test`, referring to `test:hi` (with a single colon) signals an error.

So, you are not doing anything wrong, except expecting that the REPL somehow had other package resolution rules than a source file.

Comment: So the end user of my system should just `(ql:quickload :test)` without `(in-package :test)` and then use qualified names to use external symbols? Since otherwise they could accidentally overwrite symbols of my package?

Comment: There are two cases: library and interactive system.  The former is much more common; here you selectively import from the package using the library, if at all.  If you use the REPL as a user interface for an interactive system, you typically provide a `test-user` package that imports the public symbols of `test`.  Widely used are `cl-user` and `asdf-user`, for example.

Answer (score 3):

It seems you're doing alright. If you export a function, you can access it with `package:function` (`test:sayhito`) (a colon). If you don't export it, you can still access it with a double colon: `package::function` (`test::sayhi`).

When you are *inside* a package, well, you can directly type all symbols, exported or not, that's the goal.